# How to change tooltip location for ToolStripMenuItem in ContextMenuStrip winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

In my application I have a `ContextMenuStrip` with 6 `ToolStripMenuItem`. I have added a tooltiptext to each of these items. This tooltip is displayed below my mouse location by quite a margin (see picture below).

[image: ToolTip display]

This causes issues when I use my application in full screen. Since the `ContextMenuStrip` itself is placed far down close to the border of the application this causes "flickering" when hovering my mouse over the last `ToolStripMenuItem`. Since the tooltip can't fit below the mouse it is pushed up and is placed over the mouse making the `ToolStripMenuItem` to loose focus. The tooltip is then removed which once again gives the focus to the menu item which displays the tool tip once again. This loop causes a serious flickering issue and disturbs the clicking functionality of the menu item.

Is there anyway to change the location of the displayed `ToolTip` to e.g. display to the right of the mouse instead of below it? I have tried to add a `ToolTip` directly to the menu item but this won't work since `ToolStripMenuItem` is not counted as a `Control`. I can't seem to find any settings for this in the `ToolStripMenuItem` class either.

The tooltip text is set in the designer class using the `ToolTipText` attribute in the `ToolStripMenuItem` class. As seen below:

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
   this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
   this.cmButtonDropDownMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
   this.cmButtonDropDownMenu.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
   this.RunSelectedAndRecord}; 
   

   this.RunSelectedAndRecord = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
   // 
   // RunSelectedAndRecord
   // 
   this.RunSelectedAndRecord.Image = global::AutomatedDriverTest.Properties.Resources.PlayAndRecord;
   this.RunSelectedAndRecord.Name = "RunSelectedAndRecord";
   this.RunSelectedAndRecord.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(201, 22);
   this.RunSelectedAndRecord.Text = "Run selected and record";
   this.RunSelectedAndRecord.AutoToolTip = false;
   this.RunSelectedAndRecord.ToolTipText = "Starts selected test...";
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `SetToolTip()` method when you say *this won't work since ToolStripMenuItem is not counted as a Control*? Note that the CMS is a Control, you can use its reference with `ToolTip.Show()`. Of course you have to specify the offset (relative to the CMS' bounds) at which the ToolTip is shown

Comment: Worth mentioning: you cannot set the location of the ToolTip exactly at `[ContextMenuStrip].PointToClient(MousePosition)`, because the ToolTip will overlap the Menu item (there goes the flickering). You can use, e.g., the Menu item's `Height` and add or subtract this measure to the `Y` position. Or specify any other location you prefer, it's enough it doesn't overlap the affected Menu item -- This all in case I've understood what you're looking for

Comment: @Jimi I was referring to setting a ToolTip directly to the `ToolStripMenuItem`. 

So if I understand you correctly I can add a tooltip to the CMS and then display the correct text depending on the position of the mouse (i.e. what TSMI the mouse hovers over). Then I can display the text at an offset to the right?

Comment: Yes, that's almost what I mean, except you don't need to associate a ToolTip to the CMS, just have a ToolTip Component available, then call its `Show()` method to position it where you prefer. You can pass the CMS as the IWin32Window (here, the Control is used as the base bounds reference, to which you add an offset)